# How to develop a channel-bound app in samsung tizen TV?

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I develop my app in samsung tizen TV. I don't know how to change my app to channel-bound or ticker mode.
I want to make auto start app in tizen. how can do it?
Tanks.

Platform: SAMSUNG TV
OS: tizen 2.3
TV: UAJ6200

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding below line to config.xml :

```
<tizen:category name='http://samsung.com/category/ticker'/>
```

Comment: Hi! Does ticker apps start automatically ? I mean Auto-start apps and channel bound apps, are they different ?

Comment: Yes, It start automatically. Of course you must select app in TV startup menu.